# Regex how can i get only exact part in a string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I should only catch numbers which are fit the rules.
Rules:

1. it should be 16 digit
2. first 11 digit can be any number
3. after 3 digit should have all zero
4. last two digit can be any number.

I did this way;

```
([0-9]{11}[0]{3}[0-9]{2})
```

number example:
1234567890100012

now I want to get the number even it has got any letter beginning or ending of the string like " abc1234567890100012abc"
my output should be just number like "1234567890100012"
When I add [a-zA-Z]* it gives all string.

Also another point is if there is any number beginning or ending of the string like "999912345678901000129999". program shouldn't take this. I mean It should return none or nothing.  How can I write this with  regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use look around to exclude the cases where there are more digits before/after:

`(?<!\d)\d{11}000\d\d(?!\d)`

On [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xdWj1y/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group, and match optional chars a-zA-Z before and after the group.

To prevent a partial match, you can use word boundaries `\b` or if the string should match from the start and end of the line you can use anchors `^` and `$`

```
\b[a-zA-Z]*([0-9]{11}000[0-9]{2})[a-zA-Z]*\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ZerXf/1)